# NSStackView only shows newest custom view

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsstackview

I have a custom view controller class. I want to instantiate multiple custom view controllers and add their views to my NSStackView. I add a new view to the stack view by clicking a button. The button calls this method:

```
[stackView insertView:myCustomViewController.view atIndex:0 inGravity:NSStackViewGravityBottom];
```

However, when a new view is added, it's added `stackView.spacing` below where the previous view was, but that previous view is no longer visible, however it is still listed as a view in my bottom gravity as evidenced when I call

```
NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[stackView viewsInGravity:NSStackViewGravityBottom].count);
```

I don't have this problem if I try adding `NSButton`s, so it's something to do with my custom view but I can't figure out what.

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check that your custom view has constraints (or an intrinsic content size) that completely define the height of the view. If they don't, these views are collapsing down to 0 heights (this same thing has happened to me before).

You can check if this is happening by:

```
[stackView insertView:myCustomViewController.view atIndex:0 inGravity:NSStackViewGravityBottom];
[stackView layoutSubtreeIfNeeded];
NSLog(@"%f - %d", NSHeight(myCustomViewController.view.frame), [myCustomViewController.view hasAmbiguousLayout]);
```

---

With StackView, you'll see that the later ones print "0 - 1". The heights are 0, and they're ambiguous.

Vertical NSStackView's will only *position* views vertically, but won't give specific heights. (Same for horizontal stack views and widths).

Comment: This is not solving the problem for me - I am adding NSTextField's to the stackView programatically but only one is displayed, and the stackView is not correctly sizing the subviews.  If I add them in IB they work fine.